# If my project depends on one function from scipy, does my project have to include the whole scipy package?

Tags: python, scipy, pip, pypi

So my project uses the `gaussian_filter1d` from `scipy.ndimage.filters` package. I'm am in the process of making the setup.py file that will tell pip which dependencies should be installed with my project. I really don't want my package to require a full download of scipy for one function. I realize that `gaussian_filter1d` uses other functions from scipy in its code but I was wondering if there is a way to only include the `gaussian_filter1d` and functions it requires instead of the whole scipy project.

My gut tells me no but I thought I would ask just in case :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this feature and cannot find a light-weight replacement or code it yourself, then I guess you have to include it in the requirements. If your project isn't sensitive to slug size, then adding a widely used dependency isn't really a big problem. Be sure to specify the version of scipy in your project, though.

Answer (score -2):

```
from scipy.ndimage.filter import gaussian_filter1d
```

will do the job. But any basic Python textbook will tell you that.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. When you pip install 'some_package' on the command line, pip also installs other packages you need to run said package. My question is, If someone where to pip install 'my_package' do I have to force them to install the entire SciPy package if my code only depends on one function from SciPy? So in the setup.py file can I do something similar to `from scipy.ndimage.filter import gaussian_filter1d` is my question.

Comment: Ah! The function you want to use will depend on other bits of scipy to work, and possibly other packages like numpy to work. So no you are going to have to install scipy and everything it depends on.